# NFC - Not able to detect a tag

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, open-nfc

onNewIntent(Intent intent) method not getting called.

The code i am trying is

```
public class NfcTagDetector extends Activity{

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detect_tag);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    IntentFilter discovery=new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);        
    IntentFilter techDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

    // Intent filters for writing to a tag
    intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] { discovery,ndefDetected,techDetected };
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("TAP", "onNewIntent");
}
```

}

And AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.example.detect.NfcTagDetector" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

nfc_tech_filter.xml file is

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
```

Please help...

Comment: What kind of tag are you trying to detect? I think the problem might be in your <tech-list>

Comment: @Peanut yes u are right and u know what.. the problem was my device. I was trying on Samsung S II and its NFC was defective.. Now I tried on Nexus and things are working..

Comment: @Peanut Do you know what is wrong in the tech list?

Answer (score 3):

The tech-list requires a tag to match all items in the list. That is not possible with your list. Better try:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Nd the biggest problem was, i was testing the code on a defective NFC enabled device.. thanks nyways NFC guy.. +1 for ur help..

Comment: Thanks @NFC guy. I am gonna check that.

Comment: @NFC guy, I updated the tech list, but still the app is not opening up when other device is near, it doesn't even make the nfc detect sound. Any other suggestions?